# Laravel insert array of arrays with foreign keys

Tags: arrays, laravel, insert, foreign-keys, relation

I have two tables, news and news_links. The news table looks like this (id, title, body, date_published) and the news_links look like this (id, news_id, url).

I'm trying to build a query where I can insert a news array:

```
array( 
  array(
    "id" => "123456",
    "title" => "First Title",
    "body" => "First body text",
    "date_published" => "01-01-16"
  )
  array(
    "id" => "22222",
    "title" => "Second Title",
    "body" => "Second body text",
    "date_published" => "01-01-16"
  )
)
```

This array will contain multiple array, this is just an example.

Links related to these news will also be inserted.

```
array(
  array(
    "0" => "1",
    "1" => "123456",
    "2" => "img_url"
  )
  array(
    "0" => "2",
    "1" => "123456",
    "2" => "img_url"
  )
  array(
    "0" => "2",
    "1" => "22222",
    "2" => "img_url"
  )
)
```

Will I have to build a foreach loop and run multiple queries or is there a way to run a single query and insert everything into both news and news_links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use one query to insert data in two different tables. However, you can combine several inserts for one table in one query.
It will look like

```
INSERT INTO news_links VALUES(1,123456,'url'),(2,123456,'url'),(2,22222,'url');
```

Comment: So I'll have to do some kind of implode() on my array to build the query I take it?

Comment: In Laravel you can simply do it like \DB::table('table name')->insert([['id' => 1, 'news_id' => 123456, 'url' => 'url'], [], []]) @JesperAndersen

Comment: I'll probalby have to use DB::insert() since I'm using "insert ignore into 'table'", but it's good to know I can use Query Builder like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple solution `NewsLink::insert(array);`